# Google+ REST API. Is there any way of getting from a profile URL to the Account's Id?

Tags: api, google-plus

Google + profile pages are typically referenced using a short name. eg https://plus.google.com/+JulianBond23 In the G+ takeout files in HTML, this is the link used for the account of the person Posting/Commenting. However people.get takes the userId as the parameter. eg. 106416716945076707395

Is there any way of using the URL shortname to discover the userID of the same account? In order to then do a people.get?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that people.get can be used with the +alias. So just extract the +alias from the profile page URL and use that. It wasn't immediately obvious from the docs.